# Apache fails to start on linux, with this error

Tags: linux, bash, apache, localhost, systemctl

I have been running apache2 without issues,
but after configuring some virtual hosts it failed to reload.

I edited the files in /etc/sites-available and the /etc/hosts file.

I see the following error:

```sh
sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
┌─[✗]─[rodgers@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
Nov 05 21:47:00 parrot brisk-menu[1965]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_>
Nov 05 21:47:00 parrot brisk-menu[1965]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_> 
lines 3031-3053/3053 (END)
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 42.
Nov 05 21:46:39 parrot dbus-daemon[1663]: [session uid=1000 pid=1663] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-sp>
Nov 05 21:46:39 parrot systemd[1629]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 58.
Nov 05 21:46:39 parrot dbus-daemon[1663]: [session uid=1000 pid=1663] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Nov 05 21:46:39 parrot systemd[1629]: Started Accessibility services bus.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 58.
Nov 05 21:46:39 parrot dbus-daemon[1663]: [session uid=1000 pid=1663] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested> 
Nov 05 21:46:40 parrot x-session-manager[1655]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
Nov 05 21:46:42 parrot systemd[1629]: run-user-138.mount: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Apache log to get more details about the error:
Ubuntu /var/log/apache2
CentOS or Redhat /var/log/httpd